# Download file/folder from Public AWS S3 with Python, no credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have opened a public access to S3 bucket and I need to download files / folders with files from the bucket using python. The trick is that I do not want to supply credentials (which boto3 apparently requires). Is it even possible?

Comment: In case you don't get an answer. You may have a better chance of getting an answer in "Data Science" community, because it includes data engineers who actively use AWS and python.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090830/use-boto3-to-download-from-public-bucket

Comment: Thanks @E.Serra , but unfortunately boto3 does require credentials when you set it up. At least all the resources I have seen point to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  **GetObject**  from the **S3** REST API, together with the **Requests** library in Python. If you grant READ access to the anonymous user, you can return the object without using an authorization header.

Example of such an S3 REST call::

```
> GET /example-object HTTP/1.1
> Host: example-bucket.s3.<Region>.amazonaws.com
```

Python(rough example):

```
import requests
url = '/example-object'
headers = {'Host': 'example-bucket.s3.<Region>.amazonaws.com'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

[Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)

[GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html)

Comment: After using a full `url = 'https://<example-bucket>.s3-<Region>.amazonaws.com/<path_in_bucket>`  worked like a charm!