# open() FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to read a txt file from public AWS s3 bucket with open()

```
f= open(url, "r", encoding="utf8")
```

I made sure the file is publicly accessible
However, I still get the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`open()` is looking for the file path locally on your machine.

In order to read from an S3 bucket you could use `boto3`, the AWS SDK.
Something like the below.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(PATH, 'FILENAME')
```

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62086013/download-file-folder-from-public-aws-s3-with-python-no-credentials) for getting the data using `requests` instead of `boto3` (which is arguably simpler)